# Solana programs are public by default?

Tags: solana-program

I was under the impression that Solana programs that I build out and deploy are by default private and the functions within can only be called using the keys associated when deploying the program. Is this true or are all the program functions that I build out and deploy callable and can be run by anybody?

If it is public, is there a way to make all functions only usable by myself or providing some type of password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes all programs are by default public and everyone can see the contents of any account.

You can make certain instructions so that only you can call them by adding some checks in the program.

This is how this would look like for example when you use the anchor framework:

```
const ADMIN_PUBKEY: Pubkey = pubkey!("5xpToKDYpLFQ41LhdPFVwkHTE2B7ki9vJ1dPQ9vsDLz");


    #[account(
        mut,
        address = ADMIN_PUBKEY
    )]
    pub admin: Signer<'info>,
```

Like this the instruction can only be called when you sign with the private key of: 5xpToKDYpLFQ41LhdPFVwkHTE2B7ki9vJ1dPQ9vsDLz

Here is an example of that in solana playground:
https://beta.solpg.io/tutorials/battle-coins

This is how a program looks on chain:
https://explorer.solana.com/address/BX66sQ2JAWM5D5xS5GcrZh1TULDdNZSXcS4LDUns2fMG?cluster=devnet

And this is transaction with that program:
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/2xqTCVisbMwNCWSSA77aoEHyYqSuAeLuM28yHePWPgJHKZG3C3Z8AF22UtNE8jJSbNJd1b725eGDwWVBFDPuwF8F?cluster=devnet